# JS ranged slider not working with JS canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have this 3D cube I drew with simple JS canvas lines. My problem is when I try to change one of the variables so that it can be changed manually by a slider, the lines with the variable in them won't load. I think it has something to do with the slider, because if I just assign the variable a number like 50, then it all loads perfectly fine. I will attach the broken code with the slider, and then the code that works, without the slider. I hope someone can help. Thanks!

Broken code with slider:

```js
var v = document.getElementById('v1');
var y = v.value;
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function load() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  //skyline
  ctx.moveTo(0, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(300, 50);
  //center box line
  ctx.moveTo(150, y + 30);
  ctx.lineTo(150, y + 70);
  //side lines

  //left
  ctx.moveTo(150, y + 30);
  ctx.lineTo(120, y + 25);
  ctx.moveTo(150, y + 70);
  ctx.lineTo(120, y + 55);
  //right
  ctx.moveTo(150, y + 30);
  ctx.lineTo(180, y + 25);
  ctx.moveTo(150, y + 70);
  ctx.lineTo(180, y + 55);

  //box sides
  ctx.moveTo(120, y + 25);
  ctx.lineTo(120, y + 55);
  ctx.moveTo(180, y + 25);
  ctx.lineTo(180, y + 55);


  ctx.moveTo(120, y + 25);
  ctx.lineTo(150, y + 20);



  ctx.moveTo(180, y + 25);
  ctx.lineTo(150, y + 20);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

};
window.requestAnimationFrame(load)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas><br>
  <input type="range" id="v1" min="1" max="100" value="50">


</body>

</html>
```

I don't know why the code isn't working. I don't have access to a syntax checker right now so I might have an error, but I can't see why it doesn't work.

Here is the working code without the ranged slider.

Good code, but without slider:

```js
var y = 50;
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function load() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  //skyline
  ctx.moveTo(0, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(300, 50);
  //center box line
  ctx.moveTo(150, y + 30);
  ctx.lineTo(150, y + 70);
  //side lines

  //left
  ctx.moveTo(150, y + 30);
  ctx.lineTo(120, y + 25);
  ctx.moveTo(150, y + 70);
  ctx.lineTo(120, y + 55);
  //right
  ctx.moveTo(150, y + 30);
  ctx.lineTo(180, y + 25);
  ctx.moveTo(150, y + 70);
  ctx.lineTo(180, y + 55);

  //box sides
  ctx.moveTo(120, y + 25);
  ctx.lineTo(120, y + 55);
  ctx.moveTo(180, y + 25);
  ctx.lineTo(180, y + 55);


  ctx.moveTo(120, y + 25);
  ctx.lineTo(150, y + 20);



  ctx.moveTo(180, y + 25);
  ctx.lineTo(150, y + 20);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

};
window.requestAnimationFrame(load)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas><br>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're not listening for changes on the slider in your first code example or that bit of your code is missing

Comment: Thanks! that was part of the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the range slider will be a `string` so you will have to parse it into a number via [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for your code to work.

```js
var v = document.getElementById('v1');
var y = parseInt(v.value);
//       ^---- The change I made

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function load() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  //skyline
  ctx.moveTo(0, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(300, 50);
  //center box line
  ctx.moveTo(150, y + 30);
  ctx.lineTo(150, y + 70);
  //side lines

  //left
  ctx.moveTo(150, y + 30);
  ctx.lineTo(120, y + 25);
  ctx.moveTo(150, y + 70);
  ctx.lineTo(120, y + 55);
  //right
  ctx.moveTo(150, y + 30);
  ctx.lineTo(180, y + 25);
  ctx.moveTo(150, y + 70);
  ctx.lineTo(180, y + 55);

  //box sides
  ctx.moveTo(120, y + 25);
  ctx.lineTo(120, y + 55);
  ctx.moveTo(180, y + 25);
  ctx.lineTo(180, y + 55);


  ctx.moveTo(120, y + 25);
  ctx.lineTo(150, y + 20);



  ctx.moveTo(180, y + 25);
  ctx.lineTo(150, y + 20);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

};
window.requestAnimationFrame(load)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas><br>
  <input type="range" id="v1" min="1" max="100" value="50">


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. :)

Comment: in 4 minutes I can give your a checkmark.

Comment: not to push..., but how would I make it so that it loads the code in the `load()` function when the slider is updated?

Comment: You will need to add an event listener to the `onChange` of the slider.